# Can/does Mexico check felony or warrant information upon exiting the country by air?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, mexico

Does Mexico check for felony or warrant information on US citizens when they exit Mexico by air (to fly to a non-US territory)? If so, does anyone know the proceedure they follow?

Comment: To travel back to the US? Or to travel from Mexico to somewhere else?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk To travel somewhere else. Sorry, I should have specified.

Answer (score 1):

When exiting Mexico by air, there's no border control at all. You just turn in the FMM form to a check-in clerk, and they don't check government databases (not sure they even can)

Comment: What if you haven't traveled far enough into Mexico to require an FMM?

Comment: @TravelMate Ah, so you're flying out of an airport in the border zone? In that case you'll just have to explain to the check-in clerk that you entered by land and stayed in the border zone, and as such didn't need an FMM. Like I said though, no border control on exit at airports

Comment: What about APIS reporting? Mexico does it, any idea if that is used for information checking? @Coke

Comment: @TravelMate AFAIK it'll check for overstays but that's about it.